# Empty space between Nav Bar and image above it

Tags: css

[image]

The navigation bar doesn't touch the image above it. It would only stay there if I added `top: -6px` but that doesn't work if I go full screen and probably on other resolutions.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azvk8p2t/)

```
#navbar{
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    top-margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #212121;
}
```

Comment: make both image and navbar within a div class and change the background color to black,i also faced this problem and this is my solution,i think this is not a good way,however my problem is solved :)

Comment: did you try my solution?isn't it works??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following fiddle:-

https://jsfiddle.net/nrvjh64z/1/

I have added the following:-

```
.banner {
  background-image: url("http://static.tumblr.com/ehpu61e/rOYlhep3h/header_thin_2.jpg");
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
}

<div class="banner"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain me why it doesn't work as I typed above? Why should I add a div in order to make it work?

Comment: The problem is caused by vertical-align: baseline, which is the default for most elements and indicates that that space should be reserved

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar { margin-top:0px !important; }
```

and you can also do same thing for your image containing class,
eg:

```
.image_con { margin-bottom:0px !important }
```